# Getting KnockoutJS Validation working with Bootstrap Popover

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, popover

Almost there, just need the popover to appear only after submit button is clicked and the field has an alert class added to it.

Note: Hover only works for isValid is true in the binding handler, otherwise testing for not true requires a click rather than a hover :S

http://jsfiddle.net/hotdiggity/UUb4M/

HTML:

```
<input data-bind="value: lastName, popover: isValidField" data-placement="below" data-title="Alert" data-content="We have identified this information is incorrect and must be updated."/>
```

JS:

```
self.lastName = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });
self.isValidField = ko.observable();
this.submit = function () {
    if (self.errors().length === 0) {
        alert('Thank you.');
    } else {
        self.errors.showAllMessages();
        self.isValidField(self.lastName.isValid());
    }
};
```

Binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.popover = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor(),
            valueUnwrap = ko.unwrap(value),
            allBindings = allBindingsAccessor(),
            isValid = allBindings.value;
        if (isValid) {
            $(element).popover({
                trigger: "hover"
            });
        } else {
            $(element).popover("hide");
        }
    },
    Update: //See jsfiddle link above (the same code)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working version for you. The popover will appear only if the validation for the `lastName` field is not met and only when the submit button is clicked. It will go away if the user types something into the `lastName` field. See this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UUb4M/1/)

The `update` function of a binding handler creates dependencies on observables that it accesses, so essentially the `update` of a binding handler will be triggered when that observable is changed. In your case, I did it with the `isValidField` observable. See notes in the code

```
var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.lastName = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });
    self.isValidField = ko.observable();

    // once the popover is shown, we want it to go away if the user types something
    // into the lastName field. We do this by triggering the popover binding handler
    // by changing the value of isValidField
    self.lastName.subscribe(function(val){          
        if(val && val.length > 0){ self.isValidField(true); }
    });

    // need to create your errors object
    self.errors = ko.validation.group(self);

    this.submit = function () {
        if (self.errors().length === 0) {
            alert('Thank you.');
        } else {
            self.errors.showAllMessages();

            // change the value of isValidField to trigger the popover binding handler's
            // update
            self.isValidField(self.lastName.isValid());
        }            
    };      
};

ko.bindingHandlers.popover = {

    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor(),
            valueUnwrap = ko.unwrap(value);

        if (valueUnwrap === false) {
            $(element).popover('show');
        } else {
            $(element).popover("destroy");
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks! Just wonder if there's a way of making the binding "popover: isValidField" validate for the field it's associate with, rather than having to specify each field separately as a function ie., self.lastName.subscribe(function(val)...